# editing text via python

Tags: python

i have Text file and the content is

Johan

Sara

robert

how to add next each one `:OK`

like that

Johan:OK

sara:OK

robert:OK

by python ... and thanks

Comment: Have *you* attempted anything yet? Or did you just want to be spoon fed an answer...

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print '%s:OK' % line.rstrip('\r\n')
```

Comment: dude it's showing error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hamoud\Desktop\PY.py", line 4, in <module>
    print '%s:OK' % f.rstrip('\r\n')
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'rstrip'1

Comment: He meant print '%s:OK' % line.rstrip('\r\n')

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file",inplace=1):
    print line.rstrip()+":OK"
```